# How to make an image appears from beyond the screen?

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have an image, it will actually be the image with facebook "like" button :).

I want it to slides from beyond the right side of my screen, when i.e. I scrolls my page down to the bottom. How to do it?

Maybe jquery? But how?

Comment: like [this](http://performyourmind.com/)?

Comment: Yes, like this, but from the right side and automatic - not on hoover : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the image a css `left` position bigger than you window width. Than use for example jQuery.animate to move it in.

HTML:

```
<img src="http://www.vpul.upenn.edu/platthouse/files/FB_button_1.jpg">
```

CSS:

```
img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 1000px;
}
body{
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

JS:

```
setTimeout(function(){$('img').animate({left: 10}, 500)}, 1000);
```

Example:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/snies/mRESg/)

Comment: allright, but how to set this animation in a way, that it animates only when i scroll down?

Comment: This will be left to you as an exercise. I suggest reading on events and jQuey event binding. ;-)

Comment: In other words, @snies doesn't know.  :)

Comment: @snies I totally agree with you, I was just fooling around.

Comment: guys, I've just asked : ) i was pretty sure that I have to use animation method, which i've been using in my tries - main problem is that i can't use the common .scroll event to work in a way that i want to. It means, i want it to happen, when I scroll for about 3/4 of my homepage : ], not just start scrolling.

Comment: @pawel I think, with .scroll() you are on the right track, please also look at .scrollTop()

Comment: @snies i did what i wanted to do. Just have a one more question: how can I move my image into the corner of my browser window? Not the corner of my page (because it's long), just into corner of my browser windows and move it along while i'm scrolling (fixed parameter - that's i know, i just don't know how to move it into corner of the browser window)

Comment: use css [fixed](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_position_fixed) and then just specify top, left, bottom or right to your liking (you can of course still animate those values)

Comment: Annoying how people keep restricing themselves to one answer. Take a look at my code and my example, it is exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think that [this](http://jsfiddle.net/LQS7D/) jsfiddle does what you want.

The like button is animated in by jQuery when a user has scrolled a 100 pixels down AND (what often is forgotten) the button is hidden again when the user scrolls back up.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var like = $('#fblike');

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(document).scrollTop() > 100) {
            like.animate({
                opacity: 1,
                right: 5
            }, 300);
        }
        else {
                like.animate({
                opacity: 0,
                right: -60
                }, 200);
        }        
    });
});​
```